# Doing Math on a Dynamic Html Table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, math

I want to do some basic math on a Dynamic Html Table that I have which uses JSON data loaded via ajax.

When I try to parseFloat, the code works, however it strips the decimal places from my numbers. I want this to be a restaurant bill application, so the decimals are important. `parseFloat.toFixed(2)` doesn't work either.

Besides that, I want to be able to select only a few of the rows to have the addition done as a subtotal. I can select the rows on click to highlight them. Once highlighted I could use a `if` statement to see which rows have the toggled class "Highlighted" and then do the calculation from there. Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this?

```js
const data = [ 
{pk: 1, Description: "Pizza", Price: "50.00"},
{pk: 2, Description: "Hamburger", Price: "60.00"},
{pk: 3, Description: "Coca Cola", Price: "20.00"},
{pk: 4, Description: "Fanta", Price: "20.00"},
{pk: 5, Description: "Corona", Price: "30.00"},
{pk: 6, Description: "Steak", Price: "100.00"}
]



function showTable(data) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("food_table")
  var table_data = '';
  var total = 0.00;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //To find the total value of the bill!
    total = parseFloat(data[i].Price) + total;
    //To create the rows from JSON Object
    table_data += '<tr id="contentRow">';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].pk + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].Description + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td>' + 'R' + data[i].Price + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td><input class="double" type="checkbox" /></td>';
    table_data += '</tr>';
  }
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', table_data);
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr id="contentRow">Total Bill = R' + total + '</tr>');
}

$("#food_table").on('click', '#contentRow', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});

showTable(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table " id="food_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>pk</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58568329/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant script and HTML in a [mcve]. Include an example of `data` For example what do you mean by `select only a few of the rows`? Select how? With the checkboxes? What does "does not work either" actually mean? Errors? Wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .text and find using classes instead of IDs which need to be unique

If you only want the rows with the checked boxes, you can do something like

```
$(".highlight td .double:checked").each
```

Here is working code

```js
const data = [ 
  {pk: 1, Description: "Pizza", Price: "50.00"},
  {pk: 2, Description: "Hamburger", Price: "60.00"},
  {pk: 3, Description: "Coca Cola", Price: "20.00"},
  {pk: 4, Description: "Fanta", Price: "20.00"},
  {pk: 5, Description: "Corona", Price: "30.00"},
  {pk: 6, Description: "Steak", Price: "100.00"}
]

function showTable(data) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("food_table")
  var table_data = '';
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    table_data += '<tr class="contentRow">';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].pk + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].Description + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td class="price">' + 'R<span>' + data[i].Price + '</span></td>';
    table_data += '<td><input class="double" type="checkbox" /></td>';
    table_data += '</tr>';
  }
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', table_data);
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr>Total Bill = R<span id="total">0.00</span></tr>');
}

$(function() {
  $("#food_table").on('click', '.contentRow', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    var total = 0;
    $(".highlight").each(function() {
      total += +$(this).find(".price>span").text();
    });
    $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2))
  });

  $("#food_table").on('click', '.double', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".double:checked").each(function() {
      total += +$(this).find(".price>span").text();
    });
    $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2))
  });

  showTable(data);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="food_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>pk</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Your thoughts are the same as mine :)

Comment: Except I only loop over highlighted rows. Apart from that, your code does look remarkably similar to mine, right down to the choice of class and span on the price cell

Comment: Thanks very much, this is so useful. my code works now for the subtotal. when trying to get the total i still cant have 2 decimals though? it doesnt look like i can use .text within my table rendering function.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by decimal issues. I see two decimals everywhere in the calculation above...

Comment: What subtotal? You code does not have a subtotal anywhere

Comment: i created a subtotal in the detect class Jquery instead of the total that you had put there. thanks very much, your code was spot on. However to calculate the total bill which does not depend on class i was using the parseFloat method which doesnt have decimals. Do you now how i can get the decimals?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Look at the code I provided. It has no issues with decimals. You need to show me the code (IN THE QUESTION - please do not post code in comments) for me to understand your problem

Comment: I have that in the showTable Function. "total = Number.parseFloat(x) + total;" was the code that is shown, i have since updated it to be "total = parseFloat(data[i].Price) + total;"

Comment: Sorry I missed that. That statement does not make any sense. x is always 0

Comment: You only do the bill once in your code You need to calculate each time something changes. I cannot is your code see how one would add more items so you will need to add the calculation to the change event of the checkbox

Comment: See update. It is hard to figure out why you want to have highlighted and checked treated differently but now you have the code to do so. I removed your initial calculation

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I have asked my question in a new link, please let me know if you understand what i am trying to do now that i have cleaned up the code and the question a bit. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569096/calculating-totals-and-sub-totals-of-dynamic-html-table

Comment: But why again ask a question without a snippet? It really helps answering when the code you already have  runs

Comment: I can answer the subtotal part if you tell me what you mean by subtotal. Unless you allow a quantity field per row, there is no subtotal to calculate

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [ 
{pk: 1, Description: "Pizza", Price: "50.00"},
{pk: 2, Description: "Hamburger", Price: "60.00"},
{pk: 3, Description: "Coca Cola", Price: "20.00"},
{pk: 4, Description: "Fanta", Price: "20.00"},
{pk: 5, Description: "Corona", Price: "30.00"},
{pk: 6, Description: "Steak", Price: "100.00"}
]



function showTable(data) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("food_table")
  var table_data = '';
  var total = 0.00;
  var x = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //To find the total value of the bill!
    total = Number.parseFloat(x) + total;
    console.log(total);
    //To create the rows from JSON Object
    table_data += '<tr class="contentRow">';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].pk + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td>' + data[i].Description + '</td>';
    table_data += '<td class="price">' + 'R' + '<span>' + data[i].Price + '</span></td>';
    table_data += '<td><input class="double" type="checkbox" /></td>';
    table_data += '</tr>';
  }
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', table_data);
  tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr>Total Bill = R<span id="total">' + total + '</span></tr>');
}

$("#food_table").on('click', '.contentRow', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  var total = 0;
  $("#food_table").find('.contentRow').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
      total += parseFloat($(this).find('.price>span').text());
    }
  })
  $('#total').text(total);
});

showTable(data);
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table " id="food_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>pk</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Each time a row is selected, iterate over the selected rows and calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Vue.js instead of jQuery for this case. Instead of manipulating with DOM nodes in Vue.js you just need to create view model and bind it to a template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .highlighted {background: lightyellow}
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>pk</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.pk" @click="itemClick(item)" :class="rowClass(item)">
                <td>{{item.pk}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.selected" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <span>Total: {{total}}</span>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {pk: 1, Description: "Pizza", Price: "50.00", selected: false},
                {pk: 2, Description: "Hamburger", Price: "60.00", selected: false},
                {pk: 3, Description: "Coca Cola", Price: "20.00", selected: false},
                {pk: 4, Description: "Fanta", Price: "20.00", selected: false},
                {pk: 5, Description: "Corona", Price: "30.00", selected: false},
                {pk: 6, Description: "Steak", Price: "100.00", selected: false}
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        total() {
            const result = this.items
                .filter(item => item.selected)
                .map(item => Number(item.Price))
                .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
            return result.toFixed(2);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        rowClass(item) {
            return item.selected ? "highlighted" : "";
        },
        itemClick(item) {
            item.selected = !item.selected;
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```